# how to upload Laravel project on Bitbucket?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bitbucket

i want to share my Laravel(version 5.4.12) project  with client, but i didn't use BitBucket before and i have no idea how to upload my Local project on Bitbucket with Database and how to access. My client want to update him daily.. so please help me out

Answer (score 5):

Just create a new repo on bitbucket, then select the option that reads

> I have an existing project

They will give you all instructions how to upload existing project to bitbucket.

You cannot upload your local database to bitbucket by default, unless you manually download it and place it somewhere in your project, then on your next push, it will be uploaded.

But your project already goes online with all migrations. So you can use migration on the server to install the database.

**How to link with website**

Once on bitbucket, your code is now available online. Then you need to connect on your server on ssh. Once connected, you can navigate where you want to install it and clone the repo.

after cloning the repo on the server when you want to link the website, you can run usual commands like `php artisan migrate --seed` to create and populate the database.

Make sure you create `.env` file online. It won't be available on bitbucket.

Comment: could you explain me please how to Database connect with project. I am confusing on that point .. i have already upload my project but don't know how to acess

Comment: @JamalAhmad, it sounds like you expect your code to _run_ on Bitbucket. This isn't the case. Bitbucket is a place to store, manage, and share code, but it's not a place to run PHP code. You'll need a web host for that.

Comment: @Chris yes exactly i expect that. but how to update my client and how to test this project online with client?

Comment: @JamalAhmad, what do you mean by "update my client" and "test this project online with client"? Are you talking about automated testing? Or running the code on a staging server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to expose your locally hosted project over secure tunnels to the public internet even if your local host is behind NATs and firewalls . It is very easy to use, for example after you have downloaded ngrok,  by running `ngrok http 8000` from the command line and it will give you a URL which will expose what is normally `localhost:8000` for you. Give that URL to your client and they will be able to access your localhost.

You can find ngrok here - https://ngrok.com

Answer (score 0):

You can only show the progress to the client if you have deployed the project on a server or if the client can pull from bitbucket and run on their own localhost but am assuming you are not going that way so upload it on a test server.